# PCIe peer to peer communication

Tags: pci-e, pci-bus

Can two independent devices(endpoints) communicate with each other without Root Complex being involved in PCIe (according to PCIe specification yes but how)?

How can one endpoint know address of other endpoint in case of memory and IO transactions?

How are the packets routed by switch between two downstream ports?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Should be doable in software, the cpu can assume the role of root complex.

Comment: (http://www.google.co.in/search?q=PIC+architecture&client=ubuntu&hs=5bb&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio2uzImsDMAhUixqYKHe2aBcEQ_AUIBygB&biw=1301&bih=678#channel=fs&tbm=isch&q=PIC+express+architecture&imgrc=M_xILFRtk-a9WM%3A) in this diagram How can PCIe endpoint can directly communicate with another PCIe endpoint without packet data being routed towards root complex

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/167154/can-two-pcie-endpoints-communicate-with-each-other-through-pcie-switch

Comment: @GilHamilton still not clear how one endpoint gets address of other endpoint.

Comment: I think you'd have to be told by software running "on" (that is, behind) the root complex. I know of no way you could independently discover the address range of another endpoint. The root complex is responsible for enumerating devices, setting up the logical bus hierarchy and assigning address ranges to each endpoint, and the only way of routing most transactions to an endpoint is via the address range. Your endpoint will not be able to observe any assignments other than your own (or your subordinates').

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible.

As you told Memory Write transactions requires "valid" Addr of recipient and Data and Memory read transactions requires "Vaild" Addr and data "size " required to creates write or read requests.

For the requests from Downstream port, switch takes care of routing to any Upstream (Root) or Downstream (peer to peer), by comparing with its "Base and Limit" Registers.

Switch Routing:

1. First check the address on its own bars, if it matched, it will consume. Two bars are available in each Switches.
2. If not, check its IO/P-MMIO/NP-MMIO Base and Limit Register pairs based on the request type.
3. If a TLP travels to Upstream port and if it matches to its Base and Limit Registers it will be handled as "Unsupported Request" on secondary interface. ( again it will pass to the downstream port, other than one that it received, since it may be peer-to-peer communication).
4. If not matches at any interface, it will forwarded to its primary interface as it not matches for the bridge and any function beneath this bridge.